# C#: Fire a function of an object every x seconds, without having to always set up a new object

Tags: c#

I am quite new to c# so I've run into this problem:

```
public void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            CheckTheBool();

            var mockingObject = new MockTheLocation(this);

            // Check the checkbox status 
            if (StartScreen.CheckBoxTicked == true)
            {
                mockingObject.getMockLocation2PROMODE();
                //mockingObject.Dispose(); 

            }
            else
            {

                mockingObject.getMockLocation2();
                //mockingObject.Dispose(); 

            }


        }
```

So, I build a working service class, that fires the OnTimedEvent procedure every 10 seconds. 
In this procedure, I basically start this operation from another class:

```
  public void getMockLocation2()
    {
        var mLocationManager = ctxt.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
    if ((EggService.counter % 2) == 0)
    {
        mLocationManager.AddTestProvider(LocationManager.GpsProvider, "requiresNetwork" == "", "requiresSatellite" == "",
                                  "requiresCell" == "", "hasMonetaryCost" == "", "supportsAltitude" == "",
                                  "supportsSpeed" == "", "supportsBearing" == "", Power.Low,
                                   Android.Hardware.SensorStatus.AccuracyHigh);

        Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GpsProvider);

        newLocation.Longitude = MainActivity.GlobalLongitude;
        //newLocation.Latitude = (MainActivity.GlobalLatitude + 0.00535);
        newLocation.Latitude = (MainActivity.GlobalLatitude + AddALitteToLatitude());
        newLocation.Time = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        newLocation.ElapsedRealtimeNanos = MainActivity.GlobalElapsedRealTime;
        newLocation.Accuracy = 1;

        mLocationManager.SetTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider, true);
        mLocationManager.SetTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.GpsProvider, Availability.Available, null, DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        mLocationManager.SetTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GpsProvider, newLocation);

        mocklocationhasbeenstarted = true;



        Log.Info("NORMAL MODE!: ", "Longitude: " + newLocation.Longitude + " Latitude: " + newLocation.Latitude + " ElapsedRealTime " +
        newLocation.ElapsedRealtimeNanos + " Accuracy: " + newLocation.Accuracy + " Time: " + newLocation.Time);

        counter++;
    }
    else
    {

        mLocationManager.SetTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider, false);
        mLocationManager.RemoveTestProvider(LocationManager.GpsProvider);

        counter = 0;

        Log.Info("DESTORYED!", "Fed IT UP");

    }
```

So what basically happens, is I am building a location mocker, that, while in the background, gives fake coordinates and then destroys this location and then sets it up and so on. I build it so, that on every first turn, the fake location is set and on every 2nd turn, the fake location is destroyed. I did however run into a problem now: ( or at least I think)

Since I countinue to build a new object in my service class, the removal of the fake location on every 2nd turn has nothing to do with the mocked location object I buil on every 1st turn, right?
This leads into another problem: 
How can I set my main object only once and then run two differend funtions of this object every x turn?

Comment: You can create your 'MockingObject' as a field in your class and create it once eg. in constructor.

Comment: Typically you don't control the destruction of objects in .Net, the garbage collector does this for you. The only time you need to worry about this is when your using unmanaged objects (like database connection). Then you should use `IDisposable`. If you want a singleton then you need a `static` class

Comment: @liam, i cannot make GetMockLocation2() a static method. This will only throw erros

Comment: I think I see you've created a variable called the same as the class. I'd avoid this, it's very confusing. `var MockingObject = new MockTheLocation(this);`,  `var mockingObject = new MockTheLocation(this);` would be best practice